# PHP web message for worker

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make restaurant ordering system, so customers can buy food on tablets and workers can see orders on their computers.

I already have website that will be used in webView in android app that customers will use, but there is no real ordering. [This](http://catino.co.nf/narucivanje) website will be shown on tablets.
It is HTML/CSS/JS(only for animations) website, nothing special.If you click on first image with text "predjelo", you will get popup where you can select how much of ordered will cost and how much of it you want.I tried multiple premade scripts but I cannot get them to work.
I have spent about 2.5 hours trying to find solution, but no good results. I do not want source code of something, I want somebody to tell me how to do it, to learn me and it would be nice if I get some code. I like to learn. Thanks

[image: Order website screenshot]

Comment: what is the specific piece of code you're having trouble with, and what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to on click event which will open a popup using jquery UI. See https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function makeOrder(item_id) {
            dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Make an order": makeOrder,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.dialog("open");

        }
    })
</script>
<ul>
    <li style="display: inline-block;" onclick="makeOrder('item_id')">
        <img src="img/predjelo.png" class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-18" alt="Image 1">
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="order-form" title="Make order" style="display: none">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
        <!--order form-->
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>

            <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I already have modal forms, If you click on first food it will popup. I need system that will make order go thru. Tablet is used for ordering and than when customer deciedes what he wants to order, it goes thru to workers pc and he gets notified.

Comment: Save data into the database when the user submits the order. Create new interface for the workers where list down all pending order from database.

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know how to do it, I am very new to PHP. Can I get some part of code or something like that?

Comment: What are the inputs you want to get from the customer in order to make an order?

Comment: Thank you soo much! Well, because it is food ordering system, it would be what foods and how many of them and price(im not sure still how to set it up to..:/) Thank you very much.

Comment: I have created very simple PHP scripts for you to get an idea. Check https://github.com/bgkavinga/sample-code/tree/master/order_mgt

Comment: I am really sorry, but I still do not understand, when I add them to wamp, I get lots of errors. I can provide you code that I have already premade(which is admin panel and order page without real ordering) Can I contact you somewhere, so we dont have extended discussion? (I dont have enough rep for stackoverflow chat) Thank you very much.

Comment: Mail me gihan.seneviratna@gmail.com